# Error in metadata in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have installed `hadoop`, `hive` and `MySQL` on the same server in `CENT OS`. I have also setup `MySQL` and user ID - hive has access to the database by using the following steps.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE metastore;
mysql> USE metastore;

mysql> SOURCE $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-0.10.0.mysql.sql;

mysql> CREATE USER 'hiveuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepassword'; 

mysql> GRANT all on *.* to 'hiveuser'@localhost identified by 'hivepassword';

mysql>  flush privileges;
```

My Hive-site.xml file properties are below:

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastorecreateDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveuser</value>
<description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>      
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hivepassword</value>
<description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description> warehouse </description>
</property>
```

When I give the **show tables command** inside the `hive shell` I get the following error:

> ***hive> show tables;    FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient FAILED: Execution
>   Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask***

I searched all in the internet but couldn't find the solution for my problem. Can someone please guide me, what am I missing here ?

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. First just check your hadoop daemons. All are up or not.

2. Else restart your hadoop cluster once.

3. Have you copied the jar (mysql-connector-java.***) into Hive's lib dir?

4. Which mysql version you are using. If it is very old then :

   mysql>alter database metastore_Db character set latin1;

 I think step 1 and 2 will solve your problem.
```

Comment: I have repeatedly done the first 2 steps but no use. Yes, I have done the 3rd step. Mysql version is 5.1.69.  Do you want me to do the 4th step for this version.. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the values of javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName, javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL, javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName and javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword in your jpox.properties ?

Comment: Also before firing the show databases/tables in hive console, first check mysql databases/tables are accessible or not on another console.

Comment: They are correct as I have mentioned earlier.. They are in hive-site. Xml

Comment: I can access and perform all the actions to the tables through mysql

Comment: Please check hive.metastore.schema.verification property  in your hive-site.xml. Is it true ? Just set it as false and try again.

Comment: Am not sure but may be there is some conflicts in your metastore lock file. Try to remove those *.lck files from metastore_db if any.